# Excel: Sending rows to other document and receiving output row by row?

Tags: excel

Does anyone know how to send and receive data between two documents in excel?
Each row in File_1 has inputs to and outputs from File_2.

Just doing it once is no problem using 
`=[File_2.xlsx]Sheet!$A$1`, but I cant figure out how to do it row by row.

**File_1**

This is my list with inputs and results from File_2

*Edit: File_2 is a large excel-file with manual input in one end and output in the other that is manually copied to File_1 at the moment. There is no reference to File_1 in File_2.*

```
input_col_1     output_col_1
input_col_2     output_col_2 
input_col_3     output_col_3
```

**File_2**

This is a black box calculator where one cell contains output_col_n that uses input from File_1

`output_col_n = input_col_n * 3.14`

Comment: A bit more detail on how File_2 works would help: when you say "that uses input from File_1" what do you mean?  Is File_2 a big spreadsheet with one cell where you type an input value and another cell that has the calculated output?  Or does it already refer to File_1?

Comment: Sorry, hope i can make it a bit clearer. File_2 is a large excel-file with manual input in one end and manual output in the other at the moment. There is no reference to File_1 in File_2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want to do a lot of work on File_2 (you call it a "black box"), the easiest option is to write a macro which works its way down your input column and populates your output column on File_1:

```vba
Public Sub getOutputFromFile_2()
        Dim lCurrRow As Long
        Dim wbFile_2 As Workbook
    'Check if File_2 is already open
        For Each wbFile_2 In Workbooks
                If wbFile_2.FullName = "D:\File_2.xlsx" Then Exit For
        Next
        If wbFile_2.FullName <> "D:\File_2.xlsx" Then Set wbFile_2 = Workbooks.Open("D:\File_2.xlsx")   'if not, then open it
    'populate the output column in this file
        For lCurrRow = 1 To 5
                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
                        wbFile_2.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = .Cells(lCurrRow, 1).Value
                        .Cells(lCurrRow, 2).Value = wbFile_2.Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("C5").Value
                End With
        Next lCurrRow
End Sub
```

(you'll need to amend the paths and cell/sheet references of course - and it would be good practice to make these defined constants).

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub filetransfer()
Dim File1 As Workbook
Dim File2 As Workbook
Dim File1Input As Range
Dim File1Output As Range
Dim File2Input As Range
Dim File2Output As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim iOffset As Integer

Set File1 = Application.Workbooks("FILEPATH\File1.xlsx") ' Alter file path and excel file name
Set File2 = Application.Workbooks("FILEPATH\File2.xlsx") ' Alter file path and excel file name
' Turn off screen updating and events for easier execution
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
' Open both workbooks
Application.Workbooks.Open (File1)
Application.Workbooks.Open (File2)
' Set Range of data you want to take out of File1
Set File1Output = File1.Sheets("1").Range("A1:A3") ' Replace Sheet(1) with sheet name you want and Set your actual range
' Set Range in File 2 where File 1 data will go
Set File2Input = File2.Sheets("1").Range("A1:A3") ' Replace sheet and range for your data/setup
' Set Range in File 1 where File 2 data will go
Set File1Input = File1.Sheets("1").Range("A1:A3") ' Replace sheet and range
' Set Range of data you want to take out of File2
Set File2Output = File2.Sheets("1").Range("A1:A3")
' Set our row number integer
i = 1
' Start stepping through each row of data in File 1 output range
For Each r In File1Output.Rows
' copy the data and paste it to File2 Input Range
r.Copy
File2Input(i, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues ' This does a paste on A1 with i = 1. If i = 2 this will paste on A2
iOffset = i + 1
i = iOffset
Next r
' You can do more stuff below this like use another loop for copying from file 2 to file 1.
' You can also perform calculations before copying or pasting if necessary.
' Or you could paste in a different format, or paste a formula
' Pasting a formula would require a nested loop to handle each cell within each row of the range

' Make sure you turn screen updating and events back on
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I didn't test this explicitly, but it should work.